# Angular routing

Tags: angularjs

Buenas noches estoy intentando usar el generador de Angular de Yeoman, y todo bien, pero cuando intento configurar el sistema de rutas con `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!')` las rutas fallan debido a que el sistema de ruta agrega un # extra en el Path.

Por ejemplo sin la configuración es:

> localhost:puerto/#/vista

pero al agregar el prefijo se convierte en:

> localhost:puerto/#!/#vista

y se agrega ese segundo # junto al nombre de mi vista lo que causa que no se encuentre la vista, si yo manualmente borro ese # la vista se renderiza con normalidad.

¿que configuración me falta? saludos!!!

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que lo que te falta es agregar:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate de que tus enlaces estén sin el **#**, así: `<a ng-href="/ejemplo"></a>` y también de tener tu `.config` implementado de la siguiente manera:

```js
ejemploApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/ejemplo',{
        templateUrl: 'ejemplo.html',
        controller: 'ejemploCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'ejemplo'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/error404',
      });
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
  }]);
```